# How do you get mouse wheel to scroll the page and not the cursor?

Tags: 18.04, mouse, scrolling, mouse-scroll

I apologize in advance if this has already been asked. I have searched for this solution for a couple hours now and could not find what I'm looking for.

I am primarily a Windows user. In Windows, if I scroll up or down with the mouse wheel in a text editor, the entire window moves. In Ubuntu, I notice that the mouse wheel causes the CURSOR to move, and the window only moves once the cursor reaches the edge of the window.

Is there a way to change this so that scrolling the mouse wheel causes the page to move while leaving the cursor in place?

EDIT:
This happens in Sublime Text 3 as well as in Visual Studio Code

Comment: What are you scrolling in?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1110423/edit) your question and add details.  If it is a text editor that you launch via the command line like `vi` or `nano` or `emacs` the scroll wheel will move the cursor.  If in a GUI app like `gedit` or `mousepad` the scrolling should move the page and not the cursor.

Comment: @Terrance I updated the question

Comment: That is very strange.  I have installed both, and those both scroll the window and not the cursor for me.  I installed both in the `snap` environment.  I am also running Ubuntu (Xubuntu) 18.04.  There is no settings that I can see that adjust the scroll wheel to move the cursor and not the window.

Comment: @Terrance I remembered that I'm using a program called imwheel because without it my mouse's scrolling is unusable. I disabled imwheel and this problem no longer occurs, but the wheel is also just very semi-functional. Do you have experience with imwheel by any chance?

Comment: I don't have any experience in it, but that doesn't mean that I can't install it and take a look at the app and see what it is all about.

Comment: @brianxk93 Please post your solution (that the problem was caused by the IMWheel application and disabling it gets rid of the problem) as an answer below by clicking the 'Answer your question' button. It's absolutely okay (and very much encouraged) to post an answer to your own question. For the other general issues with the scroll-wheel you may consider asking separate question(s).

Comment: @pomsky I'm not quite sure this solves it. When I disable imwheel the cursor does not move, yet there is always a delay between when I start scrolling and when the window actually moves, almost like the cursor actually needs to get to the edge of the window before the window itself moves. Of course this is purely speculation on my end, but matter of fact is that imwheel greatly improved scrolling on my computer. Without it scrolling was almost unusable.

Comment: I have the same problem. And its very strange that such obvious thing is missing. It exists on Windows for decades. Here is setting in Windows: [Mouse Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGbgl.png)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm guessing it correctly, when you scroll up/down your page via keypad's up/down arrow the page will jump but not scroll. You should consider enabling "Natural Scrolling" under Settings->Touchpad (Ubuntu 20.04).